# Comparing input character to an array of ints in C

Tags: c

I am kinda new to C and I am having trouble using If statements to compare character input from the user to an int stored in an array.

Eg:

```
    int i[2] = {1,2};
    char input[3];
    printf("Select option:");
    fgets(input,3,stdin);

    if(strcmp(*input,i[0]) == 0)
       printf("1 chosen");
    if(strcmp(*input,i[1]) == 0)
       printf("2 chosen");
```

When compiling I get a warning for both compare statements saying:

```
    warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without cast
    warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without cast
```

I understand that this maybe because Im comparing non-string elements, but how will I cast them then compare them?

When executing I get:

```
     Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: oh, you don't compare numbers that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better convert input char to int using atoi function.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

```
int i[2] = {1,2};
char input[3];
int opt=0;
printf("Select option:");
fgets(input,3,stdin);
opt = atoi(input); 
if(opt== i[0])
   printf("1 chosen");
if(opt == i[1])
   printf("2 chosen");
```

Answer (score 3):

Nobody yet has explained *why* what you are doing is incorrect, apart from saying that it is "wrong".

A string in C is just a bunch of consecutive characters in memory, where the last character in the string has a value of zero.  You can store a string in a `char` array, or you can point to somewhere in memory by using a `char` pointer (`char*`).

When you input a decimal number, you are reading individual characters that happen to be in the range `'0'` through to `'9'`, maybe prefixed by an optional `'-'`.  You read these as a string, and if you want to treat them as integers you need to convert them to an integer data type (instead of a series of `char` values).

That's where something like `atoi` helps, although it is no longer fashionable.  You should use `strtol`.  [There is a whole family of these functions for dealing with `unsigned`, `long long`, or combinations thereof, as well as `double` and `float` types].

That tackles roughly half of your question.  Now, you are using `strcmp` and expecting it to work.  There are a couple of things wrong with what you are doing.  The major error is that you can't treat an integer as a string.  If you really want to use string comparison, you have to convert the integer to a string.  That means you do the reverse of what `strtol` does.

That's a bigger discussion, and in your case it is not the correct way so I won't go into it.  But I'd like to point out that, all things being equal, you are sending the wrong types to `strcmp`.  It expects two `char*` pointers (`const char *`, really).  What you have done is dereferenced your `input` pointer to a `char` for the first element, and then pass an `int` for the second.

```
strcmp(*input,i[0])
```

A pointer is basically just a number.  It gives the memory address of some data.  In this case, the data is expected to be `char` type (single bytes).  The `strcmp` function is expecting valid memory addresses (stuff that's actually in your stack or heap).  But what you give it is `*input` (the value of the first character in your input string) and `i[0]` (the number `1`).

Those compiler warnings were telling you something quite important, you know! =)

So, just for completeness (although others have answered this already), you should forget the string comparisons (and make a mental note to learn more about strings in C), and do this:

```
int value = strtol( input, NULL, 10 );

if( value == i[0] )
   printf("1 chosen");
if( value == i[1] )
   printf("2 chosen");
```

There are other ways to go about this.  I could talk about how to convert single-digit numbers from a string, but I think I have already ranted for long enough.  Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the various methods listed as answers to your qn.

Why don't you take the user input as int??

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

int i[2] = {1,2};
int input;
    printf("Select option:");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    if(input==i[0])
       printf("1 chosen");
    if(input==i[1])
       printf("2 chosen");

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use scanf instead of fgets:

```
int input;
printf("Select option:");
scanf("%d", &input);
if (input == i[0])
```

etcetera.

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Simple_input_and_output#Input_using_scanf.28.29

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the input string vs. some known strings.  But you're comparing the first character vs. some ints.  `strcmp()` will do what you need if you pass it the right arguments: two strings.

Answer (score 0):

here you are trying to compare a string to an integer using strcmp:

```
if(strcmp(*input,i[0]) == 0)
```

that won't work.

you could do that way:

```
const char *numbers[2] = {"1", "2"};
char input[3];
printf("Select option:");
fgets(input,3,stdin);

if(strcmp(*input, numbers[0]) == 0)
    printf("1 chosen");
if(strcmp(*input, numbers[1]) == 0)
    printf("2 chosen");
```

where you compare two strings, instead of comparing a number to a string

or you could convert the input string to an int using sscanf or atoi

```
int i[2] = {1,2};
char input[3];
int num;

printf("Select option:");
fgets(input,3,stdin);

sscanf(input, "%d", &num);

if(num == i[0])
   printf("1 chosen");
else if(num == i[1]) 
   printf("2 chosen");
```

i didn't compile them though, maybe there's sth which i am missing but that's the general idea

Comment: or, like in SuvP's answer, simply take the user input as int.

Answer (score 0):

Use `atoi`. it will convert your string to integer

```
 int i[2] = {1,2};
    char input[3];
    printf("Select option:");
    fgets(input,3,stdin);

    if(atoi(input)==i[0]))
       printf("1 chosen");
    if(atoi(input)==i[1]))
       printf("2 chosen");
```

Comment: atoi() is dangerous, in a similar fashion to gets(), you can have UB without a lot of care.  You should use strtol() in newer code.